# All the cells of Gridview must turn into editable mode on a button click(Not the hyperlink edit button)

Tags: c#, gridview

I'm building a winform application wherein I have a Gridview and its datasource is of a Datatable. I have a button below the gridview.

On clicking the button, all the cells of Gridview must turn into editable mode.

It would be great help if someone could help on this.

```
private void EDIT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.EditIndex = -1;        
    }
```

It does not work. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can anyone answer please? It’s very urgent

Answer (score 0):

There is a property **EditMode** in a **DataGridView** control.

If you want to set editMode

```
this.datagridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
```

And then set **readonly** to false

Otherwise, if you want to disable the edit mode, you can set edit mode programmatically and then readonly to true.

A simple way is to set readonly to true or false

See this [documentation] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-specify-the-edit-mode-for-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control) from microsoft